# При дебаге в Visualstudio Code происходит выход в файл crtexe.c

Tags: c, json, visual-studio-code

Столкнулся с проблемой: во время отладки программы на языке C в visual studio code, а именно когда дохожу до закрывающей фигурной скобки `int main(int argc, char** argv)` дальнейшее нажатие клавиши <kbd>F10</kbd> не приводит, как раньше было к завершению отладки, а открывает пустой файл `crtexe.c` по такому пути:

```
C: > M > mingw-w64-crt-git > src > mingw-w64 > mingw-w64-crt > crt > crtexe.c
```

Вот мой простой код:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
      int first, second, temp;
      printf("Enter first number: ");
      scanf("%d", &first);
      printf("Enter second number: ");
      scanf("%d", &second);
    
      // value of first is assigned to temp
      temp = first;
    
      // value of second is assigned to first
      first = second;
    
      // value of temp (initial value of first) is assigned to second
      second = temp;
    
      // %.2lf displays number up to 2 decimal points
      printf("\nAfter swapping, first number = %d\n", first);
      printf("After swapping, second number = %d\n", second);
      return 0;
    }
```

Мой `launch.json`:

```
    {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C/C++: g++ build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\a.out",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file"
        },
        {
            "name": "(Windows) Запустить",
            "type": "cppvsdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "Введите имя программы, например: ${workspaceFolder}/a.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "console": "externalTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Как это исправить, чтобы после последней фигурной скобки у меня отладка автоматически завершилась?

**P.S:** из установленных плагинов у меня: C/C++(Microsoft), C/C++ Extension Pack(Microsoft), C/C++ Themes, CMake, Cmake Tools, Code Runner.

Comment: Это нормально, отладка должна завершаться, когда завершается программа.

Comment: Нет, отладка так никогда не заканчивалась. Конкретно сколько работал в visual studio code в конце отладки после последней фигурной скобки был просто выход из режима debug + немного строк в консоли gdb. И никакого выхода в файл crtexe.c  НИКОГДА не было! Вот о что я хочу донести!